# Client based Table/Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC, I only done a basic tutorial with a standard application for editing an existing table, adding rows, view it, etc.

So there was a static view, static controller and a static model, which represented 1 table in the database.

Now I wonder how should that work, if I don't know yet, how the model is going to look like.
In my case, the client can first create a table, where he defines, which rows and what datatypes, etc. and then he can edit the table.

Is there a standard way for dynamic models, or is mvc the wrong way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC works fine for this. With MVC, I just split each necessary bit of code up into the three categories. So try to think in an "MVC" Way.

`The logic that is needed to connect to the database - Definitely a Model.`

`The displaying of the data in a structured table - Definitely a view.`

`The communication between the data gathered with the logic, and the displaying of that data - Definitely a controller`

The idea of MVC is to separate the back end logic from the displaying of said logic. This helps to separate the two distinct parts of your project, and is generally considered good practice.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I understand the idea of mvc, but now I don't have a static model, which I can define hard coded in my model class.  I have a model which is created by the client at runtime.

Comment: Are you looking for the logic to connect to the database?

Comment: An example: the client needs a new table 'pets', which is not in the database. Now the client creates the table 'pets' with fields: id, name, animal type.    But as this is a new table in database, there is no MVC Model in my application. So I wonder how do I have to design the model, to represent the just new created table.

Comment: By generalizing your class. Instead of having fields "id" and "name", have one list "fields", which is populated when the table is pulled from the database, and passed in via the constructor for the model class.

Comment: Ok, that's a possibility. I should thought about that before , by myself :) thank you

Comment: Okay, well given that this is a potential answer to your question could you please mark it for future readers?